# TypeScript definition for array properties

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a type for an array with properties on it. For the life of me I cant figure out how to add typings to this (or even if it's possible?).

```
// Font weight scale
const fontWeights: FontWeights = [300, 400, 500];

// Font weight aliases
fontWeight.light = fontWeights[0];
fontWeights.normal = fontWeights[1];
fontWeights.bold = fontWeights[2];
```

I tried this with no success.

```
type FontWeightAbsolute = "bold" | "normal" | number;

type Globals = "-moz-initial" | "inherit" | "initial" | "revert" | "unset";

// from https://www.npmjs.com/package/csstype
type FontWeightProperty = Globals | FontWeightAbsolute | "bolder" | "lighter";

export type FontWeights = FontWeightProperty[] & {
      light: number;
      normal: number;
      bold: number;
    };
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you want to create an array with properties, perhaps an enum is what you're looking for?

Comment: What are `Globals` and `FontWeightAbsolute`?

Comment: @Terry ahh that's a great idea. Ill give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* do this:

```
type FontWeightAbsolute = "bold" | "normal";
type Globals = "-moz-initial" | "inherit" | "initial" | "revert" | "unset";

type FontWeightAsString =
  | Globals
  | FontWeightAbsolute
  | "bolder"
  | "lighter";

enum FontWeightAsNumber {
    Light = 300,
    Normal = 400,
    Bold = 500,
}

type FontWeight = FontWeightAsString | FontWeightAsNumber;

const weights: FontWeight[] = [
    'inherit',
    400,
    FontWeightAsNumber.Bold,
    123, // Should not be possible!
];
```

But it's not entirely type-safe. You can still pass a number like `123` to `weights`. A type-safe approach:

```
declare namespace FontWeight {
    type AsString =
      | "bold"
      | "normal"

    type AsNumber =
      | 300
      | 400
      | 500

    type Global =
      | "-moz-initial"
      | "inherit"
      | "initial"
      | "revert"
      | "unset"
}

type Weight = 
  | FontWeight.AsString
  | FontWeight.AsNumber
  | FontWeight.Global

const weights: Weight[] = [
  300,
  400,
  'inherit',
  "unset"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Array cannot have properties

you can use enums

```
const enum Direction {
    Light = 300,
    Normal = 400,
    Bold = 500
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to be really pedantic about `font-weight` typing (the default `CSSStyleDeclaration` has `font-weight` typed as `string`, but you can always do more), you will have to include the following:

- Accepting absolute values like `normal` and `bold`
- Accepting relative values like `bolder` and `lighter`
- Accepting any numeric values
- Global values such as `inherit`, `initial`, and `unset`

If you want to perform numeric weight value to weight name mapping, that will be a separate enum that has no bearing on the type, since technically `font-weight` can accept *any numerical value*.

```
enum FontWeightMapping {
    LIGHT = 300,
    NORMAL = 400,
    MEDIUM = 500,
    BOLD = 700
}

type Global = 'initial' | 'inherit' | 'unset';
type FontWeightRelativeNames = 'bolder' | 'lighter';
type FontWeightNames = 'light' | 'normal' | 'medium' | 'bold';

type FontWeight = number | FontWeightRelativeNames | FontWeightNames | Global;

// Then you can do something like this:
let fontWeight: FontWeight;
fontWeight = 100;
fontWeight = FontWeightMapping.LIGHT;
fontWeight = 'light';
```